# make bubble that move around the screen like facebook messanger

Tags: java, android, android-facebook

I want to develop app in that i want to create a bubble like facebook messenger, i can move bubble around the screen on any view, also can delete the bubble same as facebook messanger does , it same looks like facebook messenger app is working

i have no idea how to start developing that, is there any other example then please suggest me

it should look like below picture (it is taken from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca&hl=en)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check this [Creating a Floating Window out of your App](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2488094)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its call Global HeadView.

Try this out

https://github.com/PomepuyN/AndroidDemo/tree/master/GlobalViewHead

This has very good explanation how Views can be added using Service and Window Manager.

Also Broadcast Receiver is implemented which will trigger when the boot is completed and that will start the service.

Comment: your suggestion example working fine but if i want to close that bubble then how i remove/close that bubble/chat head ?

Comment: Well it depends on your flow. You have two choices. Remove View from Window Manager. ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Service.WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(viewToBeRemoved); Or simply change the visibility option. :)

Comment: i got error **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager**

Comment: Make sure you are passing same object.